# Can not execute powershell 5.0 script as azure webjob

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs, powershell-5.0

When I do on my azure site in kudu cmd:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

then I get **4.0** for powershell.

I want to extract a zip file but I get this error from my webjob log file:

```
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: ERR ] + Expand-Archive $output -DestinationPath $env:WEBROOT_PATH
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Expand-Archive:String) [], Comm 
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: ERR ]    andNotFoundException
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: ERR ]  
[02/02/2017 21:37:20 > b2afe2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Well the Expand-Archive needs powershell **5.0** but how can I upgrade that on my azure site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell 5.0 is not yet supported in Azure Functions, but we are looking to add that in the coming months. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4987e93-8617-43a7-969f-cc49aa723245/powershell-v5 for another instance of the question.